Print Contents of SYS_REFCURSOR returned from a function
I have a function which returns an array datatype as SYS_REFCURSOR.
How do I print the contents of the SYS_REFCURSOR ?
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE ADR_REC as object ( rid varchar2(100));

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE ADR_TAB as as table of ADR_REC;

proc get1 ( out_cursor out SYS_REFCURSOR )
as   
    v1 ADR_TAB := ADR_TAB();

    v1 := F1;
 
end;

function F1 ( ) return ADR_TAB
BEGIN
..
END;

begin
 proc_get1 ( );
 
 

end;
